# Postgresql - How to find continuity of id's

Tags: sql, postgresql

So i have this task on our company postgresql database.

I need to find all discontinuity in dates between the same ID's.
Here is example how it look's on db. There is ID, next we have column 'valid_from' and 'valid_to'.

As you can see only on rows 1 and 2 there is discontinuity between columns 'valid_to' to 'valid_from'.

Between rows 2>3>4 everything is ok.

```
    id                  valid_from          valid_to
1   Name_of_record1     10.10.2011 17:26    21.07.2021 02:47
2   Name_of_record1     28.08.2021 13:00    11.09.2021 21:12
3   Name_of_record1     11.09.2021 21:12    13.09.2021 05:42
4   Name_of_record1     13.09.2021 05:42    31.12.9999 00:00
```

Comment: Use Lag() / Lead()

Answer (score 1):

Using the window function [LAG()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) you can retrieve a column value from a row before the current row, so if previous row `valid_to` value is different from actual row `valid_from` value, you have a discontinuity.

```
SELECT id, valid_from::date, valid_to::date,
       CASE WHEN valid_from::date != LAG(valid_to::date) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY valid_from)
            THEN false ELSE true END AS continuity
FROM t;
```

`LAG()` will be return `null` for the first row of each group (rows with the same `id`, because there is not previous row with the same `id`). `Continuity` is set to `true` for the first row.

**Output**:

When `continuity` is `false` there is a discontinuity.

| id | valid_from | valid_to | continuity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2011-10-10 | 2021-07-21 | t |
| 1 | 2021-08-28 | 2021-09-11 | f |
| 1 | 2021-09-11 | 2021-09-13 | t |
| 1 | 2021-09-13 | 9999-12-31 | t |

Answer (score 1):

You may use `LEAD` to confirm that the values are continuous. eg

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        LEAD("valid_from",1,"valid_to") OVER (
            PARTITION BY "rec_name"
            ORDER BY "valid_from"
        )="valid_to" as continuity
     FROM
         my_table
) t
ORDER BY "id";
```

| id | rec_name | valid_from | valid_to | continuity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name_of_record1 | 10.10.2011 17:26 | 21.07.2021 02:47 | false |
| 2 | Name_of_record1 | 28.08.2021 13:00 | 11.09.2021 21:12 | true |
| 3 | Name_of_record1 | 11.09.2021 21:12 | 13.09.2021 05:42 | true |
| 4 | Name_of_record1 | 13.09.2021 05:42 | 31.12.9999 00:00 | true |

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        LEAD("valid_from",1,"valid_to") OVER (
            PARTITION BY "rec_name"
            ORDER BY "valid_from"
        )="valid_to" as continuity
     FROM
         my_table
) t
WHERE continuity=true
ORDER BY "id";
```

| id | rec_name | valid_from | valid_to | continuity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Name_of_record1 | 28.08.2021 13:00 | 11.09.2021 21:12 | true |
| 3 | Name_of_record1 | 11.09.2021 21:12 | 13.09.2021 05:42 | true |
| 4 | Name_of_record1 | 13.09.2021 05:42 | 31.12.9999 00:00 | true |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gLSHAPYvKFWzcQ3qfYreYE/0)

Let me know if this works for you.